# how to make an android application that runs in background and notify user whenever a file is downloaded into device

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Is there any way to create an android application that runs in background and notifies user whenever an file is downloaded or received via bluetooth in the device

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) class for remote URLs. Or write your own `Service` which gets started at a certain point (possibly on boot with a `BootReceiver` or on Bluetooth connection). But you'll have to manager your own threading.

If you use an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), it runs in the background and can perform whatever task you'd like. You can also make sure it doesn't get killed by calling `startForeground` to make it less likely that your service will get killed.